# Advice for best way to use old 32 bit machines

Tags: mysql, distributions, 32bit

Most PCs at work are 64 bit by now, although we still old 32 bit ones.

We are not in a position to just throw them away, but of course we don't want to drag down the entire workplace just to keep compatibility to them.

At this point all I want is the capability to connect to a MySQL 8.x database for basic CRUD operations, preferably through web applications.

Which combination of Linux distro and browser can provide this functionality while being the least demanding of the hardware?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that your question may receive close votes for "attracting opinion-based answers". You may want to add more details to the question, in particular what hardware you are talking about (otherwise no one will be able to determine if a specific distribution is "too demanding").

Comment: Define "old": CPU RAM Storage

Answer (score 0):

I have used both Debian and Zorin on old 32-bit laptops and both worked well.

There are lots of options, have a look at https://www.debugpoint.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/

Answer (score 0):

As a general suggestion for old machines, I've had good results on old (15+ years) 32bit hardware with [TinyCore Linux](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/)

Despite supporting 32bit hardware, it's built on modern concepts and has a fairly comprehensive [package repository](http://tinycorelinux.net/3.x/tcz/), including browsers and database tooling.